# PHP setcookie issue

Tags: php, cookies

After a user signs in and his password is verified, I need to store his username in a cookie. I tried to simply add `setcookie()` when the password is successfully verified in the section that looks like  `if ( $password_match == $user_login_password ) {...` but for some reason it doesn't seem to be working. I can't set cookies when a user successfully logins with correct password/username. Is there some reason you can't setcookies from inside a function?

```
    public function write($p) {

    if ( $_POST['user_login_username'] )
      $user_login_username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_login_username']);

    if ( $_POST['user_login_password'] )
      $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_login_password']);
      $password .= 'some_Salt';
      $user_login_password = hash('sha256', $password);
    } elseif ( $user_login_username && $user_login_password ) {
        $q = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$user_login_username'";
        $r = mysql_query($q);

        if ( $r !== false && mysql_num_rows($r) > 0 ) {
            while ( $a = mysql_fetch_assoc($r) ) {
            $password_match = stripslashes($a['password']);
            }

            if ( $password_match == $user_login_password ) {

                echo $this ->display_login('Correct!');

                setcookie('user','some_username');

            } else {
                echo $this ->display_login('Wrong Password!');
            }

        } else {
            echo $this ->display_login('That username does not exist.');
        }



      return;

     } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: How exactly are you determining it's not working?

Comment: Try setting the cookie's path to `/`?

Comment: That looks very dangerous. What if the user finds out what the admin's username is? The user just changes the cookie, and bam, he's logged in as admin.

Comment: Im using developer tools in chrome to monitor whether or not the cookie is being set, I also have an if isset() on the display file that should trigger if the cookie is set. P.S. this isn't for anything production, Im just experimenting with PHP.

Comment: @animuson How do I change a cookie's path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh I got it. Protocol restriction with setcookie, I was trying to set it after the  tags. Thanks to everyone who looked, I should have read the documentation better. Sorry!

Comment: post your replies like this in a Comment, not as a potential answer.

Comment: Sorry - I was under the impression that the solutions to problems should be posted as an answer even when the original poster comes up with them - so that future users will be able to easily see what the solution was.

Comment: Ok! I didn't knew about that rule

Answer (score 1):

I'd do this that way:

```
function mysetcookie($name, $value, $timestamp=null, $directory='/') {
    return setcookie($name, $value, time()+$timestamp, $directory);
}
```

And I'd be using `mysetcookie()` instead of `setcookie()` :) And I'd consider reading this:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php